# Array of polygons possible?

Tags: c#, wpf

A beginner question :
In a canvas are five images.
Each one is built with 13 polygons.
Now I want to copy the color of the same parts of the
polygons to the next one.
Is it possible to create an array of 13 parts:

```
arrayA = {A_1, A_2,.. , A13}
arrayB = {B_1, B_2,.. , B13}
where A_1 to A_13 are the polygons of image A ?
e.g arrayA[0].Fill = Brushes.Red
```

Maybe that is totally stupid because I couldn't find anything about.

Thank you for some hints to search for!

Comment: What have you tried?
Where did it go wrong?
What is the error message?
Why is:
    for(int i = 0; i < 13; i++) arrayB[i].Fill = arrayA[i].Fill;
not good enough?

Comment: The declaration of the array.

Comment: A_1 is an polygon of 20 points in the canvas. ???[] arrayA = {A_1,...}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the best approach would be to use a List of T, where T is the datatype of the polygon. List offers you a lot of flexibility and easily works with LINQ.

```
var myList = new List<PolygonDataTypeName>{ A_1, A_2,.. , A13 };
```

This is just an idea. There are several ways you could do this.